# Edit Castle Windsor Xml configuration in code

Tags: .net, xml, configuration, castle-windsor, castle

I need to provide a way to edit castle windsor xml configuration through a GUI. I don't want to change xml by hand every time.

I'd like something strongly type as custom configuration settings

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [programmatic registration API](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx) as opposed to XML configuration?  I would recommend taking that approach as opposed to automating edits to your XML configuration.

Comment: How can i make an end-user configure an application without writing code with this approach? is it possible? With xml  approach i can create a configurator that edits my xml.